# Connecting to Informix with pyodbc on Centos

Tags: python, centos, informix

I'm trying to connecto my Informix DNS with pyodbc but I have the error:

```
[informix@localhost Scipts]$ ./Test1.py
Error: ('H', '[H] [unixODBC][ (4294956236) (SQLDriverConnectW)')
```

This my script and my cnx:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pyodbc
import os
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(dsn='cms_net')
```

and actually I can log in via isq:

```
isql -v cms_net

[informix@localhost Scipts]$ isql -v cms_net
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

So I don't know what could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

That error message appears to be incomplete, you should get something like "HY004", but you are getting only the first character "H".
That normally happens when the UNICODE setting in the ODBC.INI is not properly set.

The "isql" unixODBC is not Unicode, I believe there is one called "iusql" included with unixODBC which is unicode, and should 'simulate' better what you are doing from python. I guess if you try that version with the same DSN you would get the same truncated error.

For unixODBC is normally set to:

```
[ODBC]
;uncomment the below line for UNICODE connection
UNICODE=UCS-2
```

So, try adding that to your ODBC.INI

Answer (score 0):

I can't fix this error but I changed my library to informixdb so whit this library I can connect my Informix whit python using this connection:

```
cnxn = informixdb.connect('database_name@server_name', 'UID', 'PWD')
```

Hope this can help someone! :]